# Java: Maven and Mercurial: install debian package with mercurial hash as name (version) fails

Tags: java, maven, mercurial, version, dpkg

I have a Java Maven project where I successfully integrated the Mercurial Hash into the name of my debian package created. However, if I try to install my package with `dpkg -i packagename` it always fails.

My packagename looks like `project-befea875286+.deb`

However, when I try to install it, I get the error message from `»/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control«` that there are invalid charactes in my version number `»project+${buildNumber}«`

Any idea how I could solve this problem? I guess its because of the ${buildNumber} from maven, but otherwise I could not integrate the hash in the version. I get the mercurial hash by using the buildnumber-maven-plugin.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a real version number like 1.2.1 which is the usual way to define version number for artifacts in packages like deb or rpm' (more human readable than a hg hash). The most important thing is to tag the state you want to delivery in some kind of to test, prod etc. I would suggest to use the maven.version number instead which is automatically incremented if you use the maven-release-plugin for the release process. That would make life easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I want. I already increment my version number. "project" was just a example word I used. But I need additional information, just like the mercurial hash in it. Thanks anyway.